# MySQL installation error : Initializing Database

Tags: mysql, database, installation

The error is arising while installing the MySQL Server at the Configuration step.

I even tried to install this again after deleting all related files.

[image: Popup]

[image: It stops here]

Comment: Know your DBMS. MySQL <> SQL Server. I have removed the erroneous tag from your post.

Comment: Install https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows